# How to convert Json To ByteArray & support UTF8?

Tags: java, android, cordova, nfc, payload

< Pnonegap NFC reader Application >

I'm not good about the bytes parse.

**I want to get Record payload in NFC tag By make NFC reader application but I can get and read Only English Record payload (can't get and read non-english record)**

This code can covert only English to bytes ( not support non-english , ex. china japan thai )

```
static byte[] jsonToByteArray(JSONArray json) throws JSONException
{
    byte[] b = new byte[json.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
        b[i] = (byte) json.getInt(i);
    }
    return b;
}
```

(full code :https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/blob/master/src/android/src/com/chariotsolutions/nfc/plugin/Util.java)

---

I think because English and non-english use different Bytes formats.

Ex. : https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/7950705/3561034/d6f90a8e-09a2-11e4-847f-3d468ccae538.jpg

**I see this javascript code but I don't know how to adapt to my code.**

```
var utf8 = {}
utf8.toByteArray = function(str) {
    var byteArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        if (str.charCodeAt(i) <= 0x7F)
            byteArray.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
        else {
            var h = encodeURIComponent(str.charAt(i)).substr(1).split('%');
            for (var j = 0; j < h.length; j++)
                byteArray.push(parseInt(h[j], 16));
        }
    return byteArray;
};

utf8.parse = function(byteArray) {
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++)
        str += byteArray[i] <= 0x7F?
            byteArray[i] === 0x25 ? "%25" : // %
            String.fromCharCode(byteArray[i]) :
            "%" + byteArray[i].toString(16).toUpperCase();
    return decodeURIComponent(str);
};
```

---

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify what the array is meant to be. It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve, but I doubt that the (non-indented!) code you've presented is going to help you... and that's definitely not Java code.

Comment: Note that when formatting `<br>` will be escaped and displayed as "<br>", not a line break. If you want to insert a line break, end a line with two spaces to add a <br/> line break. Code blocks do not require this.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you're doing with that code, but I think the only reasonable way to convert a JSONObject to a bytearray using UTF-8 encoding is like this:

```
byte[] json_bytes = json.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Comment: I want to get Record payload in NFC tag By make NFC reader application but I can get and read Only English Record payload (can't get and read non-english record)

(full code :https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/blob/master/src/android/src/com/chariotsolutions/nfc/plugin/Util.java)

>> I good in html but not good in Android java, I know how to edit it on html but  I don't know how to edit it on android java.

I need any guide and helps.

thanks .